# how to make post action in react hook form similar to the html submit form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

how to make post action in react hook form similar to the HTML submit form, in HTML when you submit form and it goes to the next with passing the value according to the name. I want to do the same thing, with react hook form. how I cant do that thank you

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import 'react-phone-number-input/style.css'
import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-number-input'
import { formatPhoneNumber } from 'react-phone-number-input'
//import InputNumber from 'react-input-number';
import MuiPhoneNumber from 'material-ui-phone-number';
import { Textbox, Radiobox, Checkbox, Select, Textarea } from 'react-inputs-validation';
import 'react-inputs-validation/lib/react-inputs-validation.min.css';
//import updateAction from "./updateAction";

function App(props) {
  
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, errors,action} = useForm();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
  const [num, setNum] = React.useState(2.2);
  const onSubmit = data => {

   
  };

  


  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} action="www.example.com" method="POST" >
      <label></label>
      <input placeholder="Ad" name="example" defaultValue="test" ref={register}   style={{border: "1px solid black"}}/>
       <input name="email" placeholder="email"  ref={register({
          required: "Required",
          pattern: {
            value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i,
            message: "invalid email address"
          }
        })} style={{border: "1px solid black"}}
      />
   <MuiPhoneNumber defaultCountry={'us'} />

    <input
        name="exampleRequired1"
      
        style={{border: "1px solid black"}}
       
      />




   
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default App;
```